# glClientWaitSync not working on MacOS

Tags: c++, opengl

In my rendering engine I've implemented triple buffering for updating shaders buffers using glMapSubBuffer together with orphaning and fences. Everything works fine in Windows but when I run my engine on Mac a problem arises. When I call `glClientWaitSync`in order to wait for my buffers to be free, it always returns `GL_TIMEOUT_EXPIRED`, so I can't update my buffers and the engine goes on an infinite loop waiting for them to free.

I think the problem is on how I implemented triple buffering, also because I didn't gain so much performance after using this.

Basically I've done this:

1. For every shader I check if it has buffers and, if so, I use a class to handle the update of these buffers which hold 3 buffers that I create while analyzing the shader and I set the 3 fences to `0` (one for each buffer)
2. During my rendering loop I setup the data for each shader grouping the model in order to save shader switching and so I do my rendering with a per-shader cycle.
3. Then for every shader I call a function that binds its buffers in order to update them with the data of the materials and the models. I call this function passing an index that tells which of the 3 buffers of the shader to bind. This index is updated on every draw call that the main program does. The function I use to bind the buffers for update is the function A (see below)
4. After updating the buffer I draw the objects with `glDrawElementsInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, mesh->GetFacesIndicesCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0, _instances.size());` and then I create the fences for the buffer just used with the function B given below
5. Then, for the same shader just used, there could be more data so I re-do the steps a points 3 and 4 until the data that the shader has to draw finishes.

FUNCTION A:

```
bool BindForUpdate(AUint bufferIndex)
{
    if (!_created)
        return false;

    if(_fences[bufferIndex] != nullptr)
    {
        // This is the point where the rendering goes into infinite loop
        unsinged int result = glClientWaitSync(_fences[bufferIndex], 0, BUFFERS_UPDATE_TIMEOUT);
        while (result == GL_TIMEOUT_EXPIRED || result == GL_WAIT_FAILED)
            result = glClientWaitSync(_fences[bufferIndex], 0, BUFFERS_UPDATE_TIMEOUT);

        glDeleteSync(_fences[bufferIndex]);
    }

    glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, _bindingPoint, _ubos[bufferIndex]);

    glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, _bufferDataSize * _bufferLength, nullptr, GL_STREAM_DRAW);

    _updateDataBuffer = (unsigned char*)glMapBufferRange(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, _bufferDataSize, GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED_BIT);

    if (_updateDataBuffer == nullptr)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

FUNCTION B:

```
void SyncBuffers(unsinged int bufferIndex)
{
    _fences[bufferIndex] = glFenceSync(GL_SYNC_GPU_COMMANDS_COMPLETE, 0);
}
```

I think that the problem is exactly the way I'm doing triple buffering, because I use multiple times the same buffer during the same rendering cycle since the index of which buffer to use changes once per rendering cycle and not every time I bind the shaders buffers.

How could I solve this problem?

---

I just tried changing the buffer index after every call to `glDrawElementsInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, mesh->GetFacesIndicesCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0, _instances.size());` instead of changing it just once per rendering call, but still the same problem.

---

I tried forcing OpenGL to release the buffers after `glDrawElementsInstanced` calling `glFlush` and it worked for a short time. I haf OS X 10.10 and it worked with `glFlush` (there were still problems because sometimes `glFlush` was giving an exception during execution), but then I updated to OS X 10.11 and `glFlush` started giving exceptions every time, crashing the program.

And, above all, I don't think this was the right way of solving this problem at all.

Comment: You should call `glClientWaitSync()` with the `GL_SYNC_FLUSH_COMMANDS_BIT`, at least in your first call before the wait loop. Otherwise, the GL may never actually process the pending commands (it is potentially more efficient and less global han a manually  `glFlush`ing). The random exceptions sound like some error in your application logic.

Comment: You were completely right. Using `GL_SYNC_FLUSH_COMMANDS_BIT` seems to work and it solved some other problems I had (mostly caused by `glFlush`). If you post your comment as answer I'll mark it as accepted. There is something bothering me though. Forcing the buffers to flush, is it right to do it? I mean, I'm using triple buffering so that I can have a buffer occupied with data while I update another buffer for another draw call. So, if I force the buffer to flush, it's like using always the same buffer and the triple buffering is useless, right?

Comment: Well, you can't sync and have the GL run asynchrnously at the same time. If you wait for the GL to have completed a certain sequence of commands before issuing new GL commands, this implies that you impose some upper limit on the commands which might be queued up. However, a flush does not imply the queue to run empty - especially if there are other drawing commands queued up after the fence, so you will continue to queue up new commands after the wakeup before the queue runs empty. So tripple buffering is not useless per se.

Comment: Oh ok, got it. Thank you very much. As soon as you post the answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `glClientWaitSync()` with the `GL_SYNC_FLUSH_COMMANDS_BIT`, at least in your first call before the wait loop. Otherwise, the GL may never actually process the pending commands, and the wait would last forever.

Note that this is potentially more efficient that using `glFlush`. Quoting from section 4.1.2 of the [OpenGL 4.5 core profile specification](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec45.core.pdf):

> if the `SYNC_FLUSH_COMMANDS_BIT` bit is set in `flags`, and `sync` is
>   unsignaled when `ClientWaitSync` is called, then the equivalent of
>   `Flush` will be performed before blocking on `sync`.

So the flush will only be issued when the fence is not yet signaled. Ideally, you would write the code in such a way that actually waiting on the sync would be the exception, not the rule.

Comment: Of course I'll write my code in a way that waiting on the sync would be the exception, and on my PC is mostly like this, but with the Mac I tried even waiting seconds on `GL_SYNC_FLUSH_COMMANDS_BIT`, but it still returned `GL_TIMEOUT_EXPIRED`